# How to use SSL with Passphrase for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, passphrase

I am trying to deploy the PostgreSQL with CA Signed SSL Certificate and Keys (With passphrase).
When I try to start pgsql service, it is expecting the PEM password but it will not work in the interactive way.

Do we have any **non-interactive way to provide the SSL passphrase** ? (Automatic restart or stop will not work otherwise)

1. I found this article [How to enable SSL in PostgreSQL/PPAS](http://vibhork.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-ssl-in-postgresqlppas.html) referring to use `pg_ctl start -w` so that the service will ask for the SSL key passphrase.
2. I also found this article [PostgreSQL with passphrase-protected SSL keys under systemd](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-passphrase-protected-ssl-keys-systemd/) saying about the use of `ssl_passphrase_command` but which also in turn asking the PEM passphrase interactively.

Thanks

Comment: You can put the password in a file and then use `ssl_passphrase_command` to read it from that file. BUT if you store the passphrase on the machine then you might as well not have it.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thank you.
Yeah, that is the issue. I think SSL key without passphrase is better than keeping a password in plaintext file somewhere on machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following PostgreSQL parameters:

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_passphrase_command = 'echo "mypassword"'
ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = on
```

Here, `echo` is an operating system command that just echos the argument. You will have to escape special characters like `'` or `"` in the password.

Comment: @laurence-albe

Thank you. Yeah, but the passphrase is open as plain text right ?

I think SSL key without passphrase is better than keeping a password in plaintext file somewhere on machine. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You are right. But there is no real safe way to do this if you want the server to start automatically, short of a HSM or some such advanced hardware device. And the flexibility of `ssl_passphrase_command` should be enough to cater for all eventualities.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I am still checking around.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how would you make it read from environment variable though? `echo "$SSL_PASS"` seems to be saying bad decrypt. But `echo "actualPass"` itself works (actualPass is the ssl password)

Comment: @jakewong Using an environment variable should work, as long as you set that variable in the environment of the PostgreSQL server (not the interactive shell).